# scripts not working on IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

Testing my site on versions 7, 8 and 9 of Internet Explorer I notice my scripts were not working in IE7.  I opened the developer tools in IE8 (I'm using the Utilu IE collection), changed browser mode to IE7 and received a 'Expected identifier, string or number' error, it was an extra comma so I fixed it but the site stays the same, scripts are still not working.  So I go back to the developer tools, check the console but no error appears this time, as if the page had loaded properly.  It's maybe an error on my side but since the console does not show anything I don't know where else to look.

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 in case it's important.  Everything works fine in IE8 and IE9.

Note: the scripts are mostly to enable a slideshow and horizontal scrolling.

Comment: have you tried removing cache? If error persists, you need to show some code and let us know what are you expecting. URL to the page would be good.

Comment: @ysrb  Yes, I did it just in case, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Could you post a URL to the page? That will let us have a better understanding of the error.

Comment: I'm doing the testing in local, haven't uploaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your scripts for extra commas and missing semi-columns.
Further, you can try [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check your scripts.

Comment: I did not know about JSLint, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

have you declare the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

also check that your html tags are closed properly and nested properly

Comment: I do have the doctype declared, strict.  I also ran the w3c validator and the html is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Bit difficult to solve without any code, but check for duplicate ID selectors in your HTML. Old browsers will be buggy. But duplicate ID's are not standard and will mess around.